# como remover duplicado (padre) en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Hola tengo un objeto como este el cual contiene un array de letras pero dentro de este tengo otro array:

```
letras: [
  [ // array que se desea eliminar
    {
     "nombre": "a",
     "id": 1
    },
    {
     "nombre": "b",
     "id": 2
    },
  ]
]
```

Lo que espero que me devuelva es algo así, sin que retorne otro array dentro como en el ejemplo anterior:

```
letras: [
    {
     "nombre": "a",
     "id": 1
    },
    {
     "nombre": "b",
     "id": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Has probado [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)? Puedes mirar su compatibilidad en [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=flat)

Comment: Pues si el primer array solo contiene  un unico array... puedes hacer `obj.letras = obj.letras[0];`, ya si son varios podrías revisar el `flat` que te recomendo @MitaCloud

Comment: en ese caso te serviría en la posicion 0 ejemplo: letras[0]